# Div with percentage height doesn't fit in

Tags: html, css

When I assign a percentage height in the following div, why does it get out? Thanks you in advance.

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
    Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>
    <div id="div2">Test</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0     
}

#div1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height:100%;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #467
}

#div2{
    width: 50%;
    height: 99%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white
}
```

Comment: use clear both for break lines not<br>

Comment: sorry for my english, I mean that I would like the height of #div2 was 99% of the remaining space in #div1

Comment: Even without <br/>... jsfiddle.net/qQ3MT

Comment: Yeah, with javascript it's very simple, but with pure css? :P

Comment: @user2670840 : see my answer... your problem is solved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the reason why `#div2` extends below `#div1` is because in addition to being 100% the height of its parent, `#div2` is also pushed down by the four lines of text above it - so it extends exactly that distance outside of `#div1`.

How to solve this, then? Well...I can offer a CSS solution, but it's not very flexible (a solution that employs JavaScript would definitely be more scalable, and less work to maintain). I modified your HTML structure slightly, so now it looks like:

```
<div id="div1">Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <div id="div3">
        <div id="div2">Test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To clarify my changes, I added the `#div3` element around `#div2`. Now, for my CSS, I just added this definition for `#div3`, and modified the `body` CSS to:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    line-height:1.3em;
}
#div3 {
    position:absolute;
    top:5.2em;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

This approach requires that you know how far from the top of `#div1` you want `#div3` (and its child `#div2`) to start, which by extension requires you to know exactly how tall those four lines of text are. Since browsers often render text with slightly different line heights, I specified one for the `<body>`. After that, it is a fairly simple matter of multiplying that line height by the number of lines of text (four in this case), and setting that as the `top` attribute.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JZnba/) to demonstrate what this achieves. I hope this answer was clear, and is what you're looking for! If not, let me know and I'll try to help further. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks u a lot, you are my hero! :D

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

it gets out because of the overflow property you are missing. Set it to hidden on #div2 ok?

Comment: This is not the solution, the div must be high for 99% of the remaining space

Answer (score 0):

good question. `Test<br/>`'s count as extra size. same if you use padding, it counts extra size. You can use position absolute to child element. I fixed the problem. [**check this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HJq6Y/)

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a solution because the height of the div is not 99% of the remaining space, it is impossible to solve with an absolute...

Answer (score 0):

in `div1`, use `position: fixed;` instead of `position: absolute;`

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qQ3MT/2/)

Comment: Ah...unfortunately, that isn't quite right. `#div2` continues to extend outside of `#div1`, just no scrollbar is generated because `#div1` has a fixed positioning. It achieves about the same effect as applying `overflow:hidden` to `#div1` - hides the bottom of `#div2`, but doesn't actually set its height as desired. But good lateral thinking, nonetheless!